# Recursive function complexity for nested arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, big-o, nested-lists

I wrote this function in a Leetcode challenge, Its purpose is to get a list that contains integers and nested lists for example like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1,2], 4, [1, [7, 8, 9], 3]]
```

then it returns the output as a one-level list of only integers like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

So I'm trying to calculate its time and space complexity but I really don't know where to start.
This is the function:

```
def convertToOneLevelList(nestedList, result):
    for element in nestedList:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            result.append(element)
        else:
            convertToOneLevelList(element, result)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nestedList = [1, 2, 3, [1,2], 4, [1, [7, 8, 9], 3]]
    result = convertToOneLevelList(nestedList, result = [])
    print(result)
```

Comment: This function doesn't work: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isInteger'`. If I replace it with `isinstance(element, int)`, the call `convertToOneLevelList([1, 2, 3, [1,2], 4, [1, [7, 8, 9], 3]])` returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, which is not the expected output.

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry it's my bad because it was part of a class, but I've edited it now. It runs well.

Comment: It's O(n) where n is the number of ints in the list (you only look at each number once).

Comment: @thebjorn Not all of the elements of the list are integers, some of them are another lists, also some of these lists could contain integers and lists again...

Comment: Yes, but you'll only look at any one integer once, hence O(n) where n is the total number of integers. This as opposed to a sorting algorithm where you'll need to look at each element more than once. Another algorithm would e.g. be to concatenate/expand all the lists on the current level, then recurse until there are no more expansions - that would be O(m * n) where m is the maximum depth and n is the average number of ints on each level.

Comment: @thebjorn The question doesn't rule out empty lists.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not sure how that would alter the big-O behavior of the function...

Comment: @thebjorn Makes your O(number_of_ints) wrong.

Comment: @KellyBundy how so? (I guess if you want to consider e.g. `[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]], 42]`, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-) )

Comment: @thebjorn Your O(n) means there's some n0 and c such that for any input with n>=n0, the time is bounded by cn. But I can just give you an input with n=n0 and so many empty lists that it takes *more* than cn time.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll buy that. If you give an answer and leave me a comment I'll up-vote.

Answer (score -1):

Both the time and space complexity are O(n) where n is the number of ints in the list (you only look at each number once).

This as opposed to a sorting algorithm where you'll need to look at each element more than once.

Another algorithm would e.g. be to concatenate/expand all the lists on the current level, then recurse until there are no more expansions

```
def _flatten(lst, result):
    expansions = 0
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, int):
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result += item
            expansions += 1
    return expansions > 0, result


def flatten(lst):
    result = []
    keep_going, result = _flatten(lst, [])
    while keep_going:
        keep_going, result = _flatten(result, [])
    return result


print(flatten([1, 2, 3, [1,2], 4, [1, [7, 8, 9], 3]]))
```

that would be O(m * n) where m is the maximum depth and n is the average number of ints on each level, since the algorithm is iterating over the list m times.